# Registration page on flask

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask

While creating a registration page using flask, and postgreSQL for storing the credentials, the credentials are not being stored in the database, i'm new to flask.

This is the html, i wanted to submit this form to the redirection function in the flask application to get the username and password

```
<form action=" {{ url_for('redirection') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required><br>

    <label for ="password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required><br>



    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is the flask application,

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session, render_template,request
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/register")
def register():
    return render_template("registration.html")

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html") 

@app.route("/redirection", methods = ['POST'])
def redirection():
    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)", {"username": username, "password": password})
    db.commit()
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to import from flask `url_for`

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, url_for # add the url_for
```

the second thing I think you'll need to send the function the the `HTML` file as a parameter so try doing

```
return render_template("login.html", redirection=url_for('redirection'))
```

and inside the HTML page

```
<form action="{{redirection}}" method="post">....
```